# Unable to Edit Destination settings - 1and1 hosting

Tags: hosting

I am trying to host my wordpress site on 1and1 server. But I all the [help documents](http://help.1and1.com/domains-c36931/manage-domains-c79822/domain-destination-c38672/connect-your-domain-to-your-website-webspace-a599292.html) point to editing destination under domain settings in my control panel.

Unfortunately, I am unable to see that option

[image]

Could you please let me know how can I enable the option and transfer my wordpress files?

Regards,

Bengalurean

Comment: @howdy_mcgee.  Could you please un-hold?  this was successfully resolved and can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have an actual hosting account by checking your contracts section when you are logged in.  Likely you don't have an actual hosting account... after you double check that:

it should be right where you were looking:

[image]

or look for "target" 2nd item down in left column

Comment: Thank You rudtek. But is there a way to check if I have an actual hosting account? Sorry I have to ask this here, but 1and1 could not help regarding this.

Comment: look under contracts.  It will tell you what you have.

Comment: Ok.. Please check this - http://imgur.com/a/Z1MYk
does this mean I do not have a hosting account? It just says 1&1 cloud.

Comment: Exactly correct.  You'll want to call them or click add contract to get hosting started and then you'll see "edit destination".  I'll update my answer so we can close question if you don't mind, (please mark as answered) but still free free to comment and I'll keep watching.